# package.json for postgres+node+AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, sequelize.js

The Postgres interface (to a remote DB) isnt working on my node app using Sequelize. mysql works. postgres did need some kicking on my development machine, so I am not surprised it didnt just magically work. Now when sequelize attempts to use the postgres dialect it fails.
I have ssh'd  onto my instance, and the pg and pg-hstore stuff is there, but my server just crashes on start up  (I stuck an error message in just prior to sequelize init which gets printed about 16 times a restart, but I jave no other information).

I wanted to manually do some npm install -save stuff, just to get the lights on, but I cant just do that it seems (no node or npm).
Either way, I dont really want to be SSHing about, I just want to know how to install postgres node stuff on elastic beanstalk. Is there some magic I need to add in package.json, if I want this to be scalable then I assume all the into needs to go into that.

EDIT:
My problems were nothing to do with postgres at all, and everything to do with the INTERVAL data type I added to data-types.js in sequelize.
postgres installs just fine with

```
"pg":"latest"
"pg-hstore":"latest"
```

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Beanstalk is mainly designed to serve as a web server, so installing databases is outside of its comfort zone. I'd personally recommend you'd use AWS RDS with postgres, which comes pre-installed and ready to use with Elastic Beanstalk. A very simple example [can be found here](https://medium.com/@jatescher/how-to-set-up-a-rails-4-2-app-on-aws-with-elastic-beanstalk-and-postgresql-3f9f29c046e2#.inhieyeoe).
You tried to install PG manually via SSH, but that won't help, as Elastic Beanstalk loses all changes upon restart, and it will restart at its own free will without your control. So please don't count on any SSH change you make.
Now if you really need to install PG yourself, I'd go with the docker approach as you can just grab a ready made postgres installation [from here](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/).
Lastly, if you need help resolving any error you get when you install PG manually, you'll need to share the errors in this thread.

Comment: sorry that wasnt clear, the database is somewhere else (i.e an AWS DB), I am just trying to install the node interface. also, there are no discernible errors on the installation or on the initiation of my server. i.e it install cleanly and then just crashes without output upon attempting to use pg dialect in sequelize.

Comment: I have found where the node binary is and so i can at least play with ssh and work out why it bombs.

Comment: this turns out to be an issue with javascript object attribute ordering and nothing to do with postgres at all. I'll delet it but thanks again. oh, it;s bad form to delete. I'll edit the question.